# Session Storage Retrieve data

Tags: javascript

I want to properly call the data in `SessionStorage`. When I call it from the `JavaScript` it only shows two values (idno, fname) but not the lname.

```
function display(){
    var display_data = document.getElementById('display_data');
    display_data.innerHTML="";
    for(var i = 0; i < sessionStorage.length; i++){
        var a = sessionStorage.key(i);
        var b = sessionStorage.getItem(a);
        var c = sessionStorage.getItem(a);

        display_data.innerHTML +="<tr><td>"+a+"</td><td>"+b+"</td><td>"+c+"</td></tr>";
    }
}

function save(){
    var idno = document.getElementById("idno").value;
    var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
    var lname = document.getElementById("lname").value;
    sessionStorage.setItem(idno,fname,lname);
    display();
    idno.value="";
    fname.value="";
    lname.value="";
}
```

This is the HTML form :

```
<form>
    <p>Idno:<br><input type="number" id="idno" /></p>
    <p>First Name:<br><input type="text" id="fname" /></p>
    <p>Last Name:<br><input type="text" id="lname" /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" id="button" value="Submit!" /></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Where are you setting the values of session storage? where are idno, fname and lname?

Comment: you can see the HTML form their

Comment: You need to first add the values in session storage before you can retrieve them. Where are you inserting the values in session storage?

Comment: function save(){
   var idno = document.getElementById("idno").value;
   var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
   var lname = document.getElementById("lname").value;
   sessionStorage.setItem(idno,fname,lname);
   display();
   idno.value="";
   fname.value="";
   lname.value="";
  }

Comment: Add this code in the question please.

Comment: i only need to display multiple values in table

Comment: okay sir done ;)

Comment: You calling `sessionStorage.setItem(idno,fname,lname);` wrong. Its signature is `.setItem(keyName, keyValue);` So you would need to call it three times, once for each value your setting. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem) for reference.

Answer (score 3):

In `save()` you should replace `sessionStorage.setItem(idno,fname,lname);` with following

```
sessionStorage.setItem("idno", idno);
sessionStorage.setItem("fname", idno);
sessionStorage.setItem("fname", idno);
```

As `sessionStorage.setItem` accepts two arguments (as @ste2425 mentioned in a comment), first is the key, and second is the value. Key can be any string, so I just made the name of the variables as the key. You can set it as any value.

Comment: You also need to modify `display()` accordingly.

Comment: You should note that you do not have an element with id `display_data`.